# iOS stops run my code on Performance Core

Tags: ios, iphone, profiling, coreml, cpu-cores

My app uses CoreML to run neural network (CoreML use CPU for most layers). Some time my performance is very good but after 30 seconds speed become slowly (fps is much less). I profiled it and found, that iOS use performance core for my app at the beginning. After 30 seconds it stops use Performance cores and starts use effective cores (them frequency is less). You may see to on the screenshot.

[image: CPU activity graph]

qos of my queue is .userInitiated. Also I tried .userInteractive, but is don't change anything.

I assume that it is cores planning feature of iOS. But I cannot find any information about it.

Is the documentation, which describe this behavior? Can I say iOS use performance core for my app all the time?

I use iPhone XR with iOS 14.7.1.

Comment: I can't offer you any official answer for your question (I haven't touched iOS development in over a decade now), but I do recall from those days how very stringent iOS was in terms of when an application was allowed to use phone resources, and how liberally it takes them away. I wouldn't be surprised if this is some energy-saving strategy the OS is doing, either to save battery or keep the phone from overheating. You might try seeing if occasional user interaction is needed to keep the phone from taking resources from you. Or perhaps some sort of self-imposed throttling or time limit.

Comment: I was able to decrease resource usage: change ml model to use ANR more effectively.